# Is there any way to turn multiple paths combined into a single string into separate href links?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

Is there any way to turn multiple paths from a DB field into separate href links?
eg:

```
c:\MyPath\SomeFile.pdf;c:\MyPath\AnotherFile.pdf;c:\MyPath\LastFile.pdf
```

I'm able to program a single path above into a link but the SQL DB I'm using could have up to 3 separate paths to files in it.

So for example I can turn this:

```
c:\MyPath\SomeFile.pdf
```

Into this link (and make it clickable):

```
\\1.1.1.1\c$\MyPath\SomeFile.pdf
```

I'm currently able to do this by creating a few variables to hold the path and the data from the field:

```
string UNCPath = "\\\\1.1.1.1\\c$\\";
string PathToFile = (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(temp1 + temp2);
```

Some additional notes on the above:

- I also change the colon to dollar
- Of course the IP and path etc are fake

The problem is that I'm not sure what to do if the field has multiple fields.

I'm thinking a right click menu that shows all 3 (or 2 or 1) paths and make them clickable.

Or I'd have to open another form page listing them....similar to the above line.

These methods don't seem like a very good approach to me.

Is there any other decent way to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with databases. It doesn't matter where your string comes from.

Comment: Right clic and show a context-menu with the different items seems to be appropiate. Showing a new form may not help you on improving user's experience if your aim is to just let them open the files. [This other SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagrid) resource might help you.

Comment: I was thinking the same and thought string.split and a for or foreach would work but for some reason it isn't:;string[] paths = myPaths.Split(';');'
'foreach (string path in paths)'
'{'
'//MessageBox.Show(path);'
'm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(path));'
'}'

Comment: I was able to get it to work but am not sure how to access the file name itself. I tried a few things://MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
////MessageBox.Show(m.Tag.ToString());
//MessageBox.Show(m.Name.ToString());
//MessageBox.Show(m.MenuItems.ToString());
////MessageBox.Show(m.MdiListItem.ToString());
// MessageBox.Show(m.Name);
//MessageBox.Show(m.MdiListItem.Text);
//MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
//MessageBox.Show(m.MenuItems.ToString());            Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks,