# Suppress default right click menu in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I use code like this to create a right-click menu for a `datagridview`:

```
 Dim menu As ContextMenuStrip = New ContextMenuStrip

        menu.Items.Add(ShowMenuItem1, Nothing, AddressOf MenuG5_ShowMenuItem1)
        menu.Items.Add(ShowMenuItem1, Nothing, AddressOf MenuG5_ShowMenuItem2)
 menu.show
```

When a user is in edit mode and right clicks on the cell that he is editing, both the default and my own menu come up and they overlap. I have moved mine to a side but its unsightly.

How can I suppress the default right click menu and only have mine show?

Comment: How have you implemented your own context menu?

Comment: I dynamicaly create a new context menu strip when I catch a mouse down from a right mouse click if that make sence ? I added some code to hopefully make it better to understand, thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right click context menu for datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagridview)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can just set contextmenu strip visibility property to false....

Comment: Contextmenu = none on the datagridview