# How to open a context menu with right click on a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

The title pretty much says it all. Can someone explain to me how can I open a context menu by selecting and then right clicking on a `ListViewItem` of a `ListView`?

I tried using the following code

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (listView1.FocusedItem.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    } 
}
```

But I don't know how to register this event handler with the `ListView`. Every time I try I get the error that the delegates parameters are wrong because I use `MouseEventArgs` instead of `EventArgs`.

This is the wrong code I'm using to register the `EventHandler`

```
this.listView1.MouseClick += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_MouseClick);
```

Comment: Look to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437889/showing-a-context-menu-for-an-item-in-a-listview

Comment: You most likely have tried to subscribe to the wrong event. Check the designer code.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to register the event?

Answer (score 0):

bind the contextmenu to the listview using `listView1.ContextMenu=contexMenu1`

then you can use the below code in `listView1.MouseDown`

```
ListViewHitTestInfo lstHitTestInfo = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    if (lstHitTestInfo.Item != null)
                    {
                        listView1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
                    }
                }
```

this will select the listviewitem and display the contextmenu.