# Select row in DataGridView in mouse_click event

Tags: c#, datagridview, onclick

I have a `DataGridView` on a form. When I right-click a row, I need the program to open a context menu. With this context menu I want to be able to modify the data in the `DataGridView`.

I have gotten the context menu to show where I right click, but I don't know where to go from here. As I will be deleting (for example) an entire row, I need to get the index of said row and also set it to selected. I tried this with the `cell_clicked` event but I can't determine if the left or right mouse button was pressed. But with the `mouse_click` event I cannot get the row index.

Here is my code:

```
public Form()
{
   ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

   //Fill Context Menu
   MenuItem delete = new MenuItem("Delete");
   contextMenu.MenuItems.Add(delete);
}

private void grdSchedules_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
   {
      contextMenu.Show(grdSchedules, new Point(e.Y, e.Y));      
      //Get rowindex here and select row          
   }
}
```

I have tried it this way:

```
 private void grdSchedules_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) //e.Button does not work here
       {
           contextMenu.Show(grdSchedules, new Point(e.Y, e.Y));                
       }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `MousePosition` in place of `e.X` and `e.Y` in your `CellClick`.  You might have to translate the coordinates to the grid space, but that's trivial.

Comment: This should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagrid

Comment: I got it working. Edited post above to include answer...

Comment: @LeonidasFett you can answer your own question down the page. there people can vote and it's easier to find

Answer (score 14):

I created a more simple and faster generic method which works with any datagrids. This method allows selecting rows with a right click. Add this method to your DataGridViews' "MouseDown" event:

```
    public void DataGridView_RightMouseDown_Select(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the user pressed something else than mouse right click, return
        if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) { return; }

        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

        // Use HitTest to resolve the row under the cursor
        int rowIndex = dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        // If there was no DataGridViewRow under the cursor, return
        if (rowIndex == -1) { return; }

        // Clear all other selections before making a new selection
        dgv.ClearSelection();

        // Select the found DataGridViewRow
        dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Here is how I did it:

```
        private void grdSchedules_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                int currentMouseOverRow = grdSchedules.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

                for (int x = 0; x < grdSchedules.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (grdSchedules.Rows[x].Index == currentMouseOverRow)
                    {
                        grdSchedules.Rows[x].Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grdSchedules.Rows[x].Selected = false;
                    }                    
                }

                contextMenu.Show(grdSchedules, new Point(e.Y, e.Y));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could've used `grdSchedules_MouseDown` or `grdSchedules_MouseUp` events instead of `grdSchedules_MouseClick` or `grdSchedules_CellClick`.