# C# DataGridView Right Click to ContextMenu Click Retrieve Cell Value

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I have a DataGridView.  I have created a ContextMenuStrip when Right Clicking a Cell in column 4 of my DataGridView.  I am however stuck because on left clicking the ContextMenuStrip Menu Item I would like the extract the data from the cell that was right clicked.

The cell I want is the top left corner of the ContextMenuStrip which is precisely where I right clicked and points at the cell who's data I want to grab.  [The screen grab just doesn't show the mouse cursor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGtGv.jpg)

This is what I have so far:

```
GridView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView_MouseDown);

private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var ht = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            //Checks for correct column index
            if (ht.ColumnIndex == 4 && ht.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                //Create the ContextStripMenu for Creating the PO Sub Form
                ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
                ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Open PO");
                MenuOpenPO.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
                Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });

                //Assign created context menu strip to the DataGridView
                dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
            }

            else
                dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = null;
        }
    }
```

[I think this post may be what I am looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526193/2157661)

However if I change: `private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)`
to

`private void dataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)`

I am not sure how to change `GridView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.dataGridView_MouseDown);` So I don't get an error message.  Or is there a better way to do this?

***Final Solution*** With help from Gjeltema

`dataGridView1.CellMouseDown += this.dataGridView1_CellMouseDown;`

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Checks for correct column index
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            //Create the ContextStripMenu for Creating the PO Sub Form
            ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Open PO");
            MenuOpenPO.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
            Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });

            //Assign created context menu strip to the DataGridView
            dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu;
            CellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        }

        else
            dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going with the solution of that post, then note that he's subscribing to the `CellMouseDown` event, not the `MouseDown` event.  This has a different signature.

Also, as of .Net 2.0, you don't need all the delegate wrapping syntax, you can just `+=` the function that matches the signature of the event delegate, like so:

```
// Your updated MouseDown handler function with DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs
GridView1.CellMouseDown += this.dataGridView_MouseDown;
```

Then you won't have the error message, and can do what you see in the post.

Comment: Thanks!  I am still trying to wrap my head around Events and delegates.  Your solution worked for me and after changing a few lines I was able to grab the cell value after click the Context Menu.