# RadContextMenu.DropDownOpened called before RadGridView.CurrentRow is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, contextmenu, dropdown

I'm trying to change an item on my `RadContextMenu` depending on the currently selected row in my `RadGridView` (edit: `OrderList`). I want the item to be enabled if the databound item in the current row has the correct property value.

The problem is that when I directly rightclick a row to open the `RadContextmenu` the `CurrentRow` has not yet been updated, so `DropDownOpened` is called with the old row. 
If I left click or double right click it works fine.

Here's a bit of the code:

```
OrderMenu.DropDownOpened += OrderMenu_DropDownOpened;
```

And the method

```
private void OrderMenu_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GoToParentOrderBtn.Enabled = GetSelectedOrder()?.ParentOrderId != null;
}

private OrderViewModel GetSelectedOrder()
{
    return (OrderViewModel)OrderList.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
}
```

Comment: I provided an answer for your question:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [right click context menu for datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagridview)

Comment: I'm sorry - I should have specified my gridview. I'm using a RadGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not specifying that I'm using a radgridview.

I found a [related answer](http://www.telerik.com/forums/drag-row-from-one-radgrid-to-another) which helped me solve my problem.
I ended up making an extension (so I can use it all around the application) to RadGridView which fire an event on mousedown:

```
public partial class RadExtendedGridViewController : RadGridView
{
    public RadExtendedGridViewController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.MouseDown += RadExtendedGridViewController_MouseDown;
    }

    private void RadExtendedGridViewController_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var element = this.ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(e.Location);
            GridDataCellElement cell = element as GridDataCellElement;
            if (cell?.RowElement is GridDataRowElement)
            {
                Rows[cell.RowIndex].IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then changed my GetSelectedOrder to using SelectedRows instead of Current:

```
    private OrderViewModel GetSelectedOrder()
    {
        return (OrderViewModel)OrderList.SelectedRows.FirstOrDefault()?.DataBoundItem;
    }
```

And now it works as intended. Thanks for taking your time trying to help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataGridView.EndEdit();` This function commits and ends the edit operation on the current cell being edited.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620(v=vs.110).aspx)