# Right click in dataGridView without selecting row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

Is there any way to show `contextmenu` on `DataGridView` without selecting row? I want both ways to show `contextmenu` on `DataGridView` by selecting row and by not selecting row. Here is my code for showing `contextmenu` on selected row.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void ProductServicesDataGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var hti = ProductServicesDataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            ProductServicesDataGrid.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;

            ProductContextMenu.Show(ProductServicesDataGrid, e.X, e.Y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [right click context menu for datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagridview)

Comment: _”Is there any way to show contextmenu on DataGridView without selecting row?”_... yes… using the `DataGridViews` `ContextMenuStrip` will allow the user to right-click on the grid to get a context menu. Right-clicking into the grid will not select or deselect any cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that didn't help you, let's edit your code a little bit.

```
private void ProductServicesDataGrid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                 if(ProductServicesDataGrid.SelectedCells!=null)
                 {
                  // you can use selected rows in a foreach loop however you want                         
                 ProductContextMenu = new ProductContextMenu();
                     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in ProductServicesDataGrid.SelectedCells)
                      {
                      m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(cell.Value));
                      }
                      ProductContextMenu.Show(ProductServicesDataGrid, e.X, e.Y);
                 }
                else 
                {
                 // any cells are selected
                }
            }
        }
```