# Right clic on DataGridView returning cell indexes where right clic was made?

Tags: vb.net, events, datagridview, cell

I attached a ContextMenuStrip to a DataGridView, but the action it will perform will be based on the row the user right clicked onto.

I was able to retrieve coords from a left click but there is no event called CellRightClick, only CellClick or CellMouseClick... etc.
Yet I read online that it was possible to track position I/O of cells, but I'd like a more simple solution since next step is portability to a touch screen system.

EDIT: I figured out luckily that when I right click and my ContextMenu pop off, it's considered like a CellMouseLeave event aswell, so:

```
Private Sub t(Sender As Object, E As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseLeave

    LastRightClickedRowIndex = E.RowIndex

End Sub
```

might work? What do you think? Is it solid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718389/right-click-context-menu-for-datagridview this is in c# but same concept?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataGridView CellContextMenuStripNeeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontextmenustripneeded?view=netframework-4.7.2) event that occurs when a cell's shortcut menu is needed because a user right-clicks a cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(
    sender As Object, 
    e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs) 
    Handles DataGridView1.CellContextMenuStripNeeded

    MsgBox("You click row " & e.RowIndex & " / column " & e.ColumnIndex & "!")

End Sub
```